# Wikidata SPARQL filter properties by id

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, wikidata

I have the following sparql:

```
#Cats
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?prop 
WHERE 
{
  ?item ?prop wd:Q7206.
  filter not exists {?prop **FILTER** wdt:P921 }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } 
# Helps get the label in your language, if not, then en language
}
```

I want to return relations excluding P921. What should I enter instead of **FILTER**?

Comment: either `filter (?prop != wdt:P921)` or once you have multiple exclusions you can use as shortcut a list and write `filter (?prop not in (wdt:P921, wdt:P922, wdt:P923))` or indeed with only your single exclusion `filter (?prop not in (wdt:P921))`

Comment: and `filter not exist` is more for absence of whole triples, not to filter on a single node